# How to update gnuplot (4.6 to 5.0)?

Tags: updates, gnuplot

I have recently installed GNU Octave 4.0.0 and today when I checked that I have gnuplot version 4.6 although I haven't installed it. I guess it was installed during the installation of Octave. However, I would like to have one of the latest versions of gnuplot, i.e., 5.0 or 5.0.3.
What is the easiest/best way to update it?
If I uninstall it and install a newer version would that brake the installation of Octave?

Comment: ...so how does it finish? did you tried?